# new Sphinx version attempts a non-existing connection

Tags: sphinx

I recently upgraded sphinx to version 2.2.11 on Ubuntu.

THen I started getting daily emails where a process is attempting to connect and generating this error:

```
ERROR: index 'test1stemmed': sql_connect: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost'
ERROR: index 'test1': sql_connect: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost'
```

The email warning has a topic which I assume is the info regarding the root of the problem

```
. /etc/default/sphinxsearch && if [ "$START" = "yes" ] && [ -x /usr/bin/indexer ]; then /usr/bin/indexer --quiet --rotate --all; fi
```

so `/etc/default/sphinxsearch`   does have the start variable as yes.
but the `/usr/bin/indexer` is total gibberish.

Such a  user never existed on the system AFAIK.

It would be interesting to know how this process got generated, but more importantly
How can this process be safely stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen that happen, it comes from the Sphinx install 'package'. Whoever setup that package, created a cron task that does that `indexer --all` command, that just tries to reindex every index (once a day IIRC). The package maintainer thought they being helpful :)

From https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ppc64el/sphinxsearch/filelist

looks like it might be in

```
/etc/cron.d/sphinxsearch
```

You could remove that cron task, if dont want it.

Presumably you already have some other process for actually updating your actual real 'live' indexes. (either dedicated cron tasks, or maybe use RT indexes or whatever)

---

Also it seems you still have these 'test' indexes in your `sphinx.conf`. Maybe left over from the initial installation. Installing a new package I dont think would overwrite sphinx.conf to add them later?

May want to clear them out of your `sphinx.conf` if don't use them, could simplify the file.

(although possibly still want to get of the --all cron, which just blindly reindexes everything daily!)